# Search query from Google Webmaster Tools isn't found in my SERP

Tags: google-search-console, blog, blogger

I write a blog at `blogger.com`. I am using Google Webmaster Tools on my blog.

In my Webmaster tool dashboard, I can see that a particular search query has  an average position of 5. See the attached screenshot below for reference:

[image: Webmaster Tools-> Search Traffic-> Search Queries]

However, when I search the exact search query in Google, I don't see my blog in the results (at least not in the first 4 pages).

Can anyone explain this to me? Or am I misinterpreting the Webmaster Tools data?

Comment: I am noticing similar behavior for my low-traffic site. I am guessing the high ranking is given only to users with a very specific type of localization and history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found you on page 3 for the one search term I looked for. About position 34.

The search queries cover all versions of Google, eg co.uk, com, in etc and you might be appearing in different places in different versions. It also includes Google images. You can filter down to exclude various variations.

Also, to get a better picture, you would be best allowing time to build up more data as dealing with 1's and 2's isnt ideal.

[image]

Comment: Hah, was going to check this myself but couldn't read the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

The data from Google Webmaster Tools is misleading and notoriously inaccurate at best.

Take it with a pinch of salt.

Also bear in mind, this is the average position over the specified duration rather than a categoric "this is where you rank for this keyword".

Answer (score 0):

Tricky one..

Clear your browser cache, start a private / incognito browsing session and go to http://www.impersonal.me

Then configure your locale / language and Google engine, and search for your term.